# Heroku piggyback SSL with node and express - any config needed?

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku

I'm using express / node js for a simple server.

There's no need for secure https everywhere, but I do want to secure some upload form posts and responses that come back on that to phones.

So far I've setup a standard nodejs server on http with express.js.

I have an app.post('/upload'...)

I'm deployed on heroku, so I changed the app I'm testing to post the form data to **https**://myapp.herokuapp.com/upload

Is it now posting over https? And will the response be over https?

Or do I need to reconfigure the express server in some way to specifically handle that?

These uploads/responses are the only secure part, and non-visible to users (done by the phone app) - so there's no need to do full http ssl endpoint config for the whole domain/sub domain if the above piggyback solution is ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Heroku, SSL is terminated at the routing layer and a [`X-Forwarded-Proto: https`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_headers)  header is added to the request so your app can know that the request came in over SSL. In other words, from your app's perspective, the request is plain HTTP and doesn't need to do anything special, but you can always check for the `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` header if you want to make sure the request was made securely. If the request was made over SSL, the response will also be over SSL since it they are both part of the same connection.